# C++ determine if float has decimal places

Tags: c++

So I have this code to determine whether the float has any decimal places

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float c = 5.5;
    if (c % 1 == 0) {
        cout << "Is a integer" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But I keep getting this error

```cpp
||=== Build: Debug in SpecialPythagoreanTriplet (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\bartl\Documents\C++ Projects\SpecialPythagoreanTriplet\SpecialPythagoreanTriplet.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
C:\Users\bartl\Documents\C++ Projects\SpecialPythagoreanTriplet\SpecialPythagoreanTriplet.cpp|20|error: invalid operands of types 'float' and 'int' to binary 'operator%'|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

How could I do this?

Comment: You probably want [`std::fmod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod) - `if(std::fmod(c, 1.f) == 0.f) { ...`

Comment: For the built-in reminder operator, lhs and rhs must both have integral or unscoped enumeration types.